# Prove that every affine map is continuous.

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-topology, continuity

> Prove that every affine map is continuous.

I'm completely stuck on this and nothing I've tried has worked.

If $T: A \rightarrow R^k$ is the affine map, where $A$ is the affine span of an affine independent subset of $R^n$, wouldn't the continuity depend on each $n,k$ and what topology is used?

Anyone have any ideas as to how to show that this is continuous?

Answer (score 1):

Let $A=v_0-C$, where $C$ is a convex set spanned by linearly independent vertices $v_1,\dots,v_m$ (where $m\le n$). Then any $x\in A$ is written as a convex combination $x=\sum_k t_k(v_0-v_k)$ with the nonnegative scalars summing up to $1$. Take $x_{\nu}\in A$ as a convex combination $x_{\nu}=\sum_{k}t_{k,\nu}(v_0-v_k).$ Let $x_{\nu}\to x$ as $\nu\to\infty$. This is equivalent to all $t_{k,\nu}\to t_k$. Then by affinity \begin{multline}f(x_{\nu})=f\left(\sum_kt_{k,\nu}(v_0-v_k)\right)=\sum_k t_{k,\nu}f(v_0-v_k)\to\sum_kt_kf(v_0-v_k)\\=f\left(\sum_kt_{k}(v_0-v_k)\right)=f(x).\end{multline}

Comment: What is $v_0$ and why can you write $A$ in terms of $v_0-C$?

Comment: What does it mean that a subset $\{v_1,\dots,v_m\}$ of $\Bbb R^n$ is affine independent? This means that there is $v_0$ s.t. $v_0-v_k$ are linearly independent. Then a convex subset $C$ is a convex span of $v_0-v_k$. Everything is based on the fact that affine spans are tralslates of convex spans.

Comment: In the book I'm reading it just says if $A$ is the affine set spanned by the set of points, then $A = V + x_0$, where $V$ is just an $m$-dimensional sub-vector-space $V$.  So this vector space is in fact a convex set spanned that second set of points?

Comment: Yes, it;s that. Then use $V=A-x_0$ with the same effect as in my hint.

Comment: What exactly does $V -x_0$ mean if $V$ is a vector space and $x_0$ is a point?

Comment: I think it is typo, since the translated  space not with affine property, but the spirit is fine, the key is that the cofficient will converges to cooresponding part.